# Что значит "Создать поток, прослушивающий ввод с консоли и повторяющий введенные данные"?

Tags: java

> "Создать поток, прослушивающий ввод с консоли и повторяющий введенные данные."

Делаю лабораторки по Java. Вот тут задание такое и я не совсем понимаю как его делать.

Вот допустим будет объявлен экземпляр класса scaner или BufferedReader он потом передаётся в поток и там выполняет работу. Это так выглядит?

Comment: я так понимаю, что нужно в бесконечном цикле считывать строку с консоли и выдавать ее на консоль. Или нет?

Comment: Лучше уточните у вашего преподавателя детали желаемой реализации.

Comment: Какую тему проходите, многопоточность?

Comment: Просто потоки и работа с ними.

Comment: Понятие поток достаточно обширное, это обращение к данным и работа с ними во временных рамках.   Они позволяют общаться с какими-то другими сущностями. Когда вы работаете с консольным вводом/выводом, тот же System.out.println - это уже поток. Как и все  классы ввода/вывода считаются потоками Input**Stream**, Output**Stream**, FileInput**Stream**, FileOutput**Stream** и т.д. Поэтому если под потоком не понимается что-то другое, то грубо говоря от вас требуется "считать данные с консоли и повторить их на консоль", все равно без потоков вы этого не сделаете и они будут созданы в любом случае.